# Grok pattern grammar syntax

Tags: logstash, grammar, logstash-grok

This file contains the predefined Grok patterns, described using some kind o grammar. But I can't find a place where the syntax used in the grammar is explained. It would be really useful to read that file and also define custom Grok patterns. Does anybody know where I could find a descriptive? I made some research but was unable to find anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are talking about the `logstash` grok filter, the syntax seems to be described in detail in the [logstash reference manual](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-grok.html). That page says that

> The regular expression library is Oniguruma, and you can see the full supported regexp syntax [on the Oniguruma site](https://github.com/kkos/oniguruma/blob/master/doc/RE).

Google found me that page given the search `grok filter pattern`.

Comment: Oh, I missed that. It's exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!